# Calculate technical debt on manual rules

Tags: configuration, sonarqube

I am trying to import code and static code check results for APL language (there is no plugin for SonarQube). I have imported all files as txt, created manual rules and manual issue. Installed SQALE plugin and defined measures for my rules, but technical debt is not calculated.

I assume that this is because my rules are not in QualityProfile for my project (I used standart SonarWay C#, Project has C# as language), but I just can not add them there :(

Here is what I get when I try to activate them -

0 rule(s) changed, 50 rule(s) ignored in profile Sonar way - C#

Answer (score 0):

Manual rules can't have technical debt, even if you configure a remediation function for them thanks to the SQALE plugin.

Just for your information, please note that in next version of SonarQube (5.5), the concept of manual rules and manual issues is going to be dropped - see [SONAR-7470](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7470). The reason is that SonarQube should remain an automated code review tool, and not try to compete with manual code review tools that have a complete different way of working.

Also, as a side note, if you have installed the SQALE plugin (which is a commercial one), you should have purchased a license for it and therefore you get support for this. In this case, you should contact SonarSource support to get help.

Comment: thank you. I`ve got SQALE in trial. But if all this stuff is going to be dropped - my entire solution is not working one )